# Meaning of a sentence which uses "would rather"

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

[image]

I would like to know the meaning of the sentence which is underlined here in the image. The image reads as follows:

·············The text in the image begins here···········

Would rather means 'prefer' or 'would prefer'.

• I'd rather walk than wait for a bus.

• Karen would rather we kept together. (I'm asking about this one.)

• Would you rather eat now or later?

It is followed by an infinitive without to (walk) or by a clause (we kept together).

················Ends here················

I suspect that this sentence (Karen would rather we kept together.) is rather wrong and doesn't say anything – could be a printing error.

This text in the image can be found in the book "learners pocket grammar by John Eastwood, Oxford University press."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of context, the meaning of the indicated sentence is admittedly vague because it is not clear whether Karen is included in "we." But one possible meaning (and I would guess the intended meaning) is

> Karen would prefer that she and I remain a couple rather than splitting up.

Comment: For an example where "we" does not include Karen: maybe she's a tour guide leading us in a group and I'm telling my friend that he shouldn't wander off by himself: "Karen [the guide] would rather we [the tour group] kept together."

Comment: @CanadianYankee Nice.